# How to remove all except exception in string with multiple value for if-statement

Tags: c#, multiple-value

in this multiple value exception for if-statement, I accept the condition  if any value from my list is exist in the given string and then I remove this values from string:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace _01_WORKDOC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string searchin = "You cannot successfully determine beforehand which side of the bread to butter"; 
            var valueList3 = new List<string> { "successfully", "determine", "bread", "the", "to" }; 

            if (valueList3.Any(searchin.Contains)) 
            {
                string exceptions3 = "successfully determine bread the to"; 
                string[] exceptionsList3 = exceptions3.Split(' ');
                string test3 = searchin;
                string[] wordList3 = test3.Split(' ');
                string outtxt = null;
                var text = wordList3.Except(exceptionsList3).ToArray();
                outtxt = String.Join(" ", text);

                Console.WriteLine("Input: " + searchin + "\nOutput: " + outtxt + "\n");              
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how in this code keep exceptions and remove everything else, except this words. So actual result is:

```
Input: "You cannot successfully determine beforehand which side of the bread to butter"
Output: "You cannot beforehand which side of butter"
```

but what can I do if with using of this same list `var valueList3 = new List<string> { "successfully", "determine", "the", "bread", "to" };` I want get this result.

```
Input: "You cannot successfully determine beforehand which side of the bread to butter"
Output: "successfully determine the bread to"
```

Correct to say I want both for same statement:

```
 Input: "You cannot successfully determine beforehand which side of the bread to butter"
 Output A: "You cannot beforehand which side of butter"
 Output B: "successfully determine the bread to"
```

And of course I'm not asking for this:

```
var valueList3 = new List<string> { "You", "cannot", "beforehand", "which", "side", "of", "butter" };
```

but with same list:

```
  var valueList3 = new List<string> { "successfully", "determine", "the", "bread", "to" };
```

Comment: This is a confusing question.  What is your expected results exactly?

Comment: @Kinetic hello, edited, everything show above

Comment: I wrote my comment after your were done editing.

Comment: So basically you have some text in a string and a bunch of word in an array.  Your output should be the words from the array that are in the text?

Comment: @Kinetic ouput with given code is `Input: "You cannot successfully determine beforehand which side of the bread to butter"
Output: "You cannot beforehand which side of butter"` show input also. Desired out put it is if I can keep only exceptions without changing the list in the opposite words

Comment: You'll get this output using which words in valueList3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this code :

```
string text = "You cannot successfully determine beforehand which side of the bread to butter"; 
var words = new List<string>{ "successfully", "determine", "the", "bread", "to" };

var foundWords = string.Join(" ", words.Where(word => text.Contains(word)));

Console.WriteLine("Input: " + text + "\nOutput: " + foundWords + "\n");
```

Will give this output :

- Input: You cannot successfully determine beforehand which side of the bread to butter
- Output: successfully determine the bread to

Comment: exactly what I need, very useful